# Import Java Tomcat CorsFilter

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to follow https://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html to deal with my cors problem.

However on this line

> org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter
> apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter is red.

[image]

[image]

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I have the code above on my web.xml file. How do properly import org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter so that I can use the filter?

Comment: This seems like an IDE issue, not a real one.  Have you tried to run with this?  It is defined in the `catalina.jar` file.